# Shared memory atomics compile for sm_20 but not sm_13

Tags: c++, cuda, gpu, atomic, gpu-shared-memory

I am using a Tesla C1060 with 1.3 compute capability and nvcc compiler driver 4.0. I am trying to do some computation local to thread block. Each thread block is provided with a shared array which is first initialized to zero values. For synchronizing concurrent updates (addition) to shared data by threads of the thread block, I use CUDA `atomicAdd` primitive.

Once each thread block is ready with the results in its shared data array, each entry in shared data array is iteratively merged (using `atomicAdd`) to corresponding entries in global data array.

Below is a code very similar to what I basically trying to do.

```
#define DATA_SZ 16
typedef unsigned long long int ULLInt;

__global__ void kernel( ULLInt* data, ULLInt ThreadCount )
{
  ULLInt thid = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;
  __shared__ ULLInt sharedData[DATA_SZ];

  // Initialize the shared data
  if( threadIdx.x == 0 )
  {
    for( int i = 0; i < DATA_SZ; i++ ) { sharedData[i] = 0; }
  }
  __syncthreads();

  //..some code here

  if( thid < ThreadCount )
  {
    //..some code here

    atomicAdd( &sharedData[getIndex(thid), thid );

    //..some code here        

    for(..a loop...)
    { 
      //..some code here

      if(thid % 2 == 0)
      {           
        // getIndex() returns a value in [0, DATA_SZ )
        atomicAdd( &sharedData[getIndex(thid)], thid * thid );
      }
    }
  }
  __syncthreads();
  
  if( threadIdx.x == 0 )
  {
    // ...
    for( int i = 0; i < DATA_SZ; i++ ) { atomicAdd( &Data[i], sharedData[i] ); }
    //...
  }
}
```

If I compile with `-arch=sm_20` I don't get any errors. However when I compile the kernel using the `-arch=sm_13` option I get the following errors:

```
ptxas /tmp/tmpxft_00004dcf_00000000-2_mycode.ptx, line error   : Global state space expected for instruction 'atom'
ptxas /tmp/tmpxft_00004dcf_00000000-2_mycode.ptx, line error   : Global state space expected for instruction 'atom'
ptxas fatal   : Ptx assembly aborted due to errors
```

If I comment out the following two lines I don't get any errors with `-arch=sm_13`:

```
atomicAdd( &sharedData[getIndex(thid), thid );
atomicAdd( &sharedData[getIndex(thid)], thid * thid );
```

Can someone suggest what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution in CUDA C programming guide: Atomic functions operating on shared memory and atomic functions operating on 64-bit words are only available for devices of compute capability 1.2 and above. Atomic functions operating on 64-bit words in shared memory are only available for devices of compute capability 2.x and higher.

So basically I cannot use ULLInt fro shared memory here and somehow I need to use unsigned int